# What are some concrete examples of how Graph Theory can be applied to Finite State Machines?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, soft-question

Conceptually, Graph Theory is not very hard to understand, even its terminology is very intuitive, however, it appears to have a very wide range of applications, one of which is the field of Finite State Machines. I wanted to know how can Graph Theory be applied to Finite State machines beyond simple state diagrams. What are some concrete examples of the overlapping of these two fields? How else are graphs or multigraphs used for computing other than the commonly used trees?

Comment: I think that the second part of your question is too broad. With regard to automatons, the transition function can be represented as a graph, and anything you do to it in that form could be considered graph theory, e.g. checking reachibility or some minimization algorithms.